# Difference between sending text as string and text between quotation marks

Tags: c++, string, qt, stream, filepath

I use mysql++ library to connect to my database. I've created a Connection and Query:

```
Connection conn(false);
conn.connect("database", "localhost", "user", "pass");
Query query = conn.query();
```

Then I can send a query to the database like:

```
query << "select name from my_table1, my_table2 where age=20"
```

But I'd like to send a *number* variable instead of 20. I tried to do that in that way:

```
std::stringstream ss; //create a stringstream
ss << my_number //add number to the stream
std::string number = ss.str();
query << "select name from my_table1, my_table2 where age="+number;
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.
My second problem is analogous. I create an QPixmap object (here QPixmap doesn't matter anyway) and i've to give the constructor a path to my image:

```
std:string name;
(...)
std::string path = "/home/root/img/"+name+".png"; //name is a variable string
QPixmap *tmp = new QPixmap(QString::fromUtf8(path.c_str())); //conversion from string to QString
```

Comment: Can you include the exact types and declarations for `path` and `name`?

Comment: Can you elabourate on "doesnt work"? Also for your first case, you should probably move to using prepared statements.

Comment: You can rewrite your query assignment as `query << "select name from my_table1, my_table2 where age=" << my_number`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
query << "select name from my_table1, my_table2 where age="+number;
```

should be:

```
query << "select name from my_table1, my_table2 where age=" << number;
```

since `+` is not a valid C++ streams concatenation operator.

What's the problem with the QPixmap?  Maybe that should be a separate question?

Comment: Ok, first problem solved, thanks to @Jason Sperske and you. In regard to QPixmap, later I want to scale QPixmap and i get "QPixmap::scaleHeight: Pixmap is a null pixmap"

Comment: @user1830818 I really suggest a new question for that.  Sounds like your path or filename is invalid.  (try reading path.c_str() in a debugger or console output before you use it)

Comment: Hm, paths looks fine. If I put "path/to/the/file" between quotes " " instead of string, it works. But OK, I create a new question, thanks!

Comment: @kozooh Try testing if `0 == strcmp("path/to/the/file", path.c_str())`.  If the strings match it should be 0.

Comment: It equals. The problem was in QString::fromUtf8 conversion. When I give as an argument only path_c.str() then everything is fine.

Answer (score 2):

For your second issue I'd recommend changing it from this:

```
std:string name;
(...)
std::string path = "/home/root/img/"+name+".png"; //name is a variable string
```

To this:

```
const QString name;
...
const QString path = QString("/home/root/img/%1.png").arg(name);
....
QPixmap tmp(path);
```